# How do you include an entire folder of polyfills using webpack?

Tags: javascript, c#, webpack

I'm converting from BundleConfig.cs in C# to use webpack.

I have the following section as part of a specific bundle:

```
.IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/helpers/", "*.js")
```

Within this folder is a bunch of Knockout.js files like ko.datepicker, etc which amend the ko object.  Since these modules aren't actually imported/required anywhere, webpack doesn't pick them up as part of it's normal bundle.  How do you tell webpack to include all files within a given folder into the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to include them at the entry like so, using the [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) library:

```js
const glob = require('glob')
const koHelpers = glob.sync('./Scripts/helpers/*.js')

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    ...koHelpers,
    './app.js'
  ]
}
```

Of course the helpers will still rely on the `ko` object being available to them, which may require further considerations such as setting up an alias.